# Error while running build of my WeGL Unity Game with Auth0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, auth0

I am trying to connect my unity web game with auth0. The idea is to have a button on this game that redirects you to the auth0 login page. If login is done correctly the login redirects you to the page with the game.

The problem is that whenever I try to do this it throws an error like this:

```
    Uncaught abort(59) at Error
at jsStackTrace (blob:http://localhost/fe45a070-7884-4685-9ce7-c8c6586954fe:8:22295)
at Object.stackTrace (blob:http://localhost/fe45a070-7884-4685-9ce7-c8c6586954fe:8:22466)
at Object.onAbort (http://localhost/Proyecto/Build/UnityLoader.js:4:11047)
at abort (blob:http://localhost/fe45a070-7884-4685-9ce7-c8c6586954fe:8:484763)
at wasm-function[56209]:3
at wasm-function[16669]:46
at wasm-function[46796]:1456
at wasm-function[56098]:16
at Object.dynCall_iii (blob:http://localhost/fe45a070-7884-4685-9ce7-c8c6586954fe:8:459875)
at invoke_iii (blob:http://localhost/fe45a070-7884-4685-9ce7-c8c6586954fe:8:339724)
at wasm-function[46793]:388
at wasm-function[46792]:75
at wasm-function[46790]:99
at wasm-function[46789]:7
at wasm-function[47108]:69
at wasm-function[47107]:7
at wasm-function[18228]:330
at wasm-function[16690]:48
at wasm-function[17191]:1236
at wasm-function[16690]:48
at wasm-function[17240]:1090
at wasm-function[17854]:534
at wasm-function[50883]:330
at wasm-function[17181]:101
at wasm-function[16866]:152
at wasm-function[18035]:71
at wasm-function[18034]:128
at wasm-function[17061]:1169
at wasm-function[16689]:52
at wasm-function[16868]:11
at wasm-function[56136]:22
at Object.dynCall_viiiii (blob:http://localhost/fe45a070-7884-4685-9ce7-c8c6586954fe:8:476660)
at invoke_viiiii (blob:http://localhost/fe45a070-7884-4685-9ce7-c8c6586954fe:8:371147)
at wasm-function[16990]:230
at wasm-function[16988]:97
at wasm-function[16987]:83
at wasm-function[16986]:81
at wasm-function[24829]:513
at wasm-function[24828]:42
at wasm-function[24827]:93
at wasm-function[25055]:77
at wasm-function[55719]:83
at wasm-function[24386]:314
at wasm-function[48387]:21
at wasm-function[48411]:110
at wasm-function[38808]:79
at wasm-function[38809]:14
at wasm-function[17204]:152
at wasm-function[38636]:101
at wasm-function[17316]:153
```

This is the code I use to connect Unity with Auth0:

```
    public void test()
{
    var client = new AuthenticationApiClient(new System.Uri("...."));

    var authorizationUrl = client.BuildAuthorizationUrl()
        .WithResponseType(AuthorizationResponseType.IdToken, AuthorizationResponseType.Token)
        .WithClient("...")            
        .WithConnection("...")
        .WithRedirectUrl("....")            
        .Build();

}
```

I am new to Unity and Auth0. Any suggestions on what could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure on the Unity front, I know you can leverage the Universal Login to accomplish what you are looking for. I would recommend triple checking your callback URL to ensure there is no breakdown there, both in your application and your Auth0 dashboard.

- https://auth0.com/blog/game-dev-make-identity-easier-and-quicker-with-auth0/